# matching the answer in C#

Tags: c#

so i have this question :

> "1. The word 'virile' means what?\na. Like a rabbit\nb. Like a man\nc. Like a wolf\nd. Like a horse\n"
>   As you can see its one string separated with \n for each choice . (a , b , c , d )

so i wrote a code to check where is the answer whether its on a , b , c or d

```
ans = "Like a man";
if (data.Content.StartsWith("a") && data.Content.Contains(ans))
{
    Reply("a");
}
else if (data.Content.StartsWith("b") && data.Content.Contains(ans))
{
    Reply("b");
}
else if (data.Content.StartsWith("c") && data.Content.Contains(ans))
{
    Reply("c");
}
else if (data.Content.StartsWith("d") && data.Content.Contains(ans))
{
    Reply("d");
}
```

It give me 'a' as it's the answer. I know why , its because im using Startwith , which it's wrong because the (data.content) starts with the question its self since its one string .

**my question is :**
how i can make the program look for any match in the question for my answer then write whatever it was a , b , c or d

Comment: I don't know what your data.Content haves, so what about do a Split in your question and the indexes 1 to 4 are your answers, then just do the match with your ans

Comment: so i should split the string then i look for a,b,c,d ?

Comment: if you have access to the question I would split the question by \n and then a for from index 1 to <5 and check which one contains the answer.

Can you tell us what type is your data?

Comment: could you please write how i use the split method for my case if you have the time ? <3

Comment: my data in type string

Comment: check if what I wrote help you

Comment: Are you required to pose the question this way for some reason? There are much better ways to create a survey / quiz.

Comment: yep it helps a lot thank you all <3

Comment: @RufusL how ? the idea is to wait the (data.content) to put the question and my program try to match the answer if it was a,b,c or d

Comment: I would create some a class to represent the question and possible answers, and another class to hold all the questions and ask them to the user (and keep score). I'll post an example...

Comment: I suggest if you found any of the answers useful clicking the up arrows next to them to give the answerer (who volunteered their time to help you) points, especially the accepted answer.

Comment: i did that long time ago but still there's problem idk why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this LINQ solution will be helpful:

```
string input = "1. The word 'virile' means what?\na. Like a rabbit\nb. Like a man\nc. Like a wolf\nd. Like a horse\n";
string[] inputSplit = input.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string ans = "Like a man";
string result = new string(inputSplit.Where(x => x.Contains(ans))
                                     .Select(x => x[0]).ToArray());
Reply(result);
```

`result`= **b**

Answer (score 1):

Check if this helps you.

```
private string question = "1. The word 'virile' means what?\na. Like a rabbit\nb. Like a man\nc. Like a wolf\nd. Like a horse\n"; // your question

string ans = "Like a man"; // your answer
string[] allAnswers = question.Split('\n');

   for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) { // index 0 contains the question
       if (answers[i].Contains(ans)) {
            Reply(answers[i][0].ToString()); // toString since [0] returns the first char, in your case will be the answer.     
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public char GetQuestionRef(string question, string answer)
{
    string[] answers = question.Split('\n');
    char question; 

    for(int i = 1; i < answers.Length; i++)
    {
        if(answers[i].Contains(answer))
        {
            question = answers[i].Substring(0, 1);              
        }
    }

    return question;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to create a class that holds the properties of a "quiz item", such as the Question, a list of Possible Answers, and the Correct Answer Index. We can also give this class the ability to ask the question, display the answers, get a response from the user and then return true or false if the response is correct.

For example:

```
public class QuizItem
{
    public string Question { get; set; }
    public List<string> PossibleAnswers { get; set; }
    public bool DisplayCorrectAnswerImmediately { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswerIndex { get; set; }

    public bool AskQuestionAndGetResponse()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Question + Environment.NewLine);

        for (int i = 0; i < PossibleAnswers.Count; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($" {i + 1}. {PossibleAnswers[i]}");
        }

        int response = GetIntFromUser($"\nEnter answer (1 - {PossibleAnswers.Count}): ",
            1, PossibleAnswers.Count);

        if (DisplayCorrectAnswerImmediately)
        {
            if (response == CorrectAnswerIndex + 1)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nThat's correct, good job!");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nSorry, the correct answer is: {0}",
                    $"{CorrectAnswerIndex + 1}. {PossibleAnswers[CorrectAnswerIndex]}");
            }
        }

        return response == CorrectAnswerIndex + 1;
    }

    // This helper method gets an integer from the user within the specified bounds
    private int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, int min, int max)
    {
        int response;
        do
        {
            Console.Write(prompt);
        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out response) ||
                 response < min || response > max);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Now that we have a class that represents a `QuizItem`, we can create another class to represent the `Quiz` itself. This class would have a list of quiz items, would be able to present each item to the user, save the responses, and display the results of the quiz.

For example:

```
public class Quiz
{
    public Quiz(User user)
    {
        if (user == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(user));
        User = user;
        QuizItems = new List<QuizItem>();
    }

    public List<QuizItem> QuizItems { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; private set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; private set; }

    public void BeginTest()
    {
        Console.Clear();

        if (QuizItems == null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are no quiz items available at this time.");
            return;
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Welcome, {User.Name}! Your quiz will begin when you press a key.");
        Console.WriteLine($"There are {QuizItems.Count} multiple choice questions. Good luck!\n");
        Console.Write("Press any key to begin (or 'Q' to quit)...");
        if (Console.ReadKey().Key == ConsoleKey.Q) return;

        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop);
        Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);

        var itemNumber = 1;
        StartTime = DateTime.Now;

        foreach (var item in QuizItems)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Question #{itemNumber}");
            Console.WriteLine("-------------");

            itemNumber++;
            var result = item.AskQuestionAndGetResponse();
            User.QuestionsAnswered++;
            if (result) User.CorrectAnswers++;
        }

        EndTime = DateTime.Now;
        var quizTime = EndTime - StartTime;

        Console.WriteLine("\nThat was the last question. You completed the quiz in {0}",
            $"{quizTime.Minutes} minues, {quizTime.Seconds} seconds.");

        Console.WriteLine("\nYou answered {0} out of {1} questions correctly, for a grade of '{2}'",
            User.CorrectAnswers, User.QuestionsAnswered, User.LetterGrade);
    }
}
```

This class makes use of a `User` class, which is used to store the user name and their results:

```
public class User
{
    public User(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int QuestionsAnswered { get; set; }
    public int CorrectAnswers { get; set; }
    public string LetterGrade => GetLetterGrade();

    private string GetLetterGrade()
    {
        if (QuestionsAnswered == 0) return "N/A";

        var percent = CorrectAnswers / QuestionsAnswered * 100;

        if (percent < 60) return "F";
        if (percent < 63) return "D-";
        if (percent < 67) return "D";
        if (percent < 70) return "D+";
        if (percent < 73) return "C-";
        if (percent < 77) return "C";
        if (percent < 80) return "C+";
        if (percent < 83) return "B-";
        if (percent < 87) return "B";
        if (percent < 90) return "B+";
        if (percent < 90) return "A-";
        if (percent < 97) return "A";
        return "A+";
    }
}
```

This seems like a lot of work, but if you're going to ask a lot of questions, it will save time in the end by reducing duplicated code and encapsulating functionality in separate classes and methods. Adding new features will be easier, too.

To use these classes, we can simply instantiate a new `Quiz` class, pass it a `User`, populate the `QuizItems`, and then call `BeginTest`:

```
private static void Main()
{
    Console.Write("Please enter your name: ");
    var userName = Console.ReadLine();

    var quiz = new Quiz(new User(userName));
    PopulateQuizItems(quiz);          
    quiz.BeginTest();

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone!! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

I put the code to populate the quiz items in a separate method, in order to reduce the clutter in the `Main` method. Right now it just has your single question:

```
private static void PopulateQuizItems(Quiz quiz)
{
    if (quiz == null) return;

    quiz.QuizItems.Add(new QuizItem
    {
        Question = "What does the word 'virile' mean?",
        PossibleAnswers = new List<string>
        {
            "Like a rabbit",
            "Like a man",
            "Like a wolf",
            "Like a horse"
        },
        CorrectAnswerIndex = 1,
        DisplayCorrectAnswerImmediately = true
    });
}
```

Then it looks something like this:

[image]